# linq to sql ToList() method value

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, null

when there's no rows returned from the database. Will I always get a List object of Count = 0. Will there ever be a case where the List = null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list will never be `null`. LINQ operations are fluent, hence having a list returning null can break chains of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You will always get an empty list and never null if there are no rows.